# Angular/SVG - capture element width on page load

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-tootltip-pj9nt8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts)

It's a D3 chart in angular.

The chart resizes when the window is resized, re-darwing the chart using the width of the window that is captured when the resizing happens

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
    onWindowResize() {

    this.w = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;

    d3.selectAll('.bar-opacity').remove()

    this.initScales();
    this.drawUpdate(this.data);
}
```

When the page first loads I don't have a width because that happens when the window is resized.

The svg has no width when the page loads

How can I capture the width of the svg's container when the page first loads

Comment: The svg element has width in `ngOnInit` - could you use that?

Comment: I think Ive tried that but can't get it to work.

Comment: It works actual in the `ngOnInit`, I must be doing something else in my code

Comment: In your StackBlitz I just put `alert(this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth);` as the first line of `ngOnInit` - and it returns me a number (717 at the moment...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting the width calculations as the first lines of `ngOnInit`...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.w = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
  this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
  ...
```

...Seems to fix the width on page-load.

Obviously you would probably want to break those calcs into their own method as they are used in multiple places. (DRY).

Answer (score 1):

You may be facing issues because the view has not yet been drawn, try moving your logic the [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) interface, this will only be fired when the view is available. This seems to work in the demo provided.

```
export class StackedChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void
  {
      this.w = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
      this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;

      this.initScales();
      this.initSvg();
      this.drawUpdate(this.data);

      console.log(this.width);
  }
}
```